# Help to indentify this plant, please!

Tags: identification

[image]Please help me to know if this is a future healthy and beautiful flower or a weed in my pot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Look around for similar plants (but adult). In which continent/region are you?  BTW, to me it seems a tree.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very similar to [the Red Canadian Maple Tree (Acer Rubrum](https://www.mailordertrees.co.uk/products/acer-rubrum-red-canadian-maple-tree)

[image]